# angular - how to write correct ngIf condition - is array length is bigger then 1

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have angular code and I put condition like this:

```
<li *ngIf="carProfiles$.length > 1">
```

and this works, but this `.length` is red in my editor and it writes

```
unresolved variable length
```

I'm worried about this because no matter this code works it seems I did something wrong. In the ts file:

```
readonly carProfiles$: Observable<Profile[]>;
```

and inside constructor:

```
this.carProfiles$ = this.allProfiles$.pipe(map((profiles) => profiles.filter((p) => ProfileHelper.isCar(p))));
```

Any help? DO I need to worry about why text .length is red and did I write condition in the correct way?

Comment: im using phpstorm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to check an array length. You are trying to check the observable's length (and is not correct) which emits an array. Instead you can first extract the emitting array inside observable by using `async` pipe, then check for length. This `async` pipe is subscribing to this `Observable` in the backgorund and unsubscribing from it.

```
<li *ngIf="(carProfiles$| async)?.length > 0">
```